# Typescript with MongoDB findOne method not working with generic

Tags: mongodb, typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing a class to clean up a lot of my existing database code. The first step for this was writing a class to manage `Collection`s for me, which I attempted to do using a class with a generic.

```js
interface MongodbItem {
    _id?: ObjectID
}

class CollectionManager<DataType extends MongodbItem> {
    database: Database;
    collection: Collection<DataType>;
    // ...
    async get(id?: ObjectID) {
        if (!id) return await this.collection.find({}).toArray();
        return await this.collection.findOne({ _id: id });
    }
}
```

However, despite defining the `DataType` generic as having that `_id` Typescript gives me the following error (On the line with the `.findOne`):

```
Argument of type '{ _id: ObjectID; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<DataType>'.
  Type '{ _id: ObjectID; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof DataType]?: Condition<DataType[P]>; }'
```

reading through the handbook it looks like extending the generic in the way I am should enforce that it has an `_id` property, so I do not know why this error is still occuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be a but with Typescript itself:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/40584
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/39358

Solved using workaround

```js
return this.collection.findOne({ _id: id } as FilterQuery<DataType>);
```